# Wrong timezone on specifc years/months

Tags: javascript

Why javascript is giving me different timezones in different dates?

[image: specific date]

```js
const a = new Date()
console.log(a)
// Thu Nov 18 2021 10:14:12 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
const b = new Date(1991, 1, 15)
console.log(b)
// Fri Feb 15 1991 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)
```

Comment: Daylight savings time?

Comment: Sounds unlikely but maybe Daylight saving in that time?

Comment: [DST was in sporadic use in Brazil until 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Brazil). What you're seeing in 1991 was the result of such daylight savings legislation that set the clocks differently from the rest of the year.

Comment: Anyone can help with the question? Why folks are giving negative avaliation?

Comment: Because the answer is in the comments

Comment: Is it my fault? I really what to understand to improve next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because Daylight saving time is cancelled in 2019 for Brasil so now Brasil is GMT+3 and before 2019 it was GMT +2. Moment JS updated its library - https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5246